# Square summable coefficients in infinite linear combination.

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, inner-products

[image]

> I understand the reasoning behind all this paragraph, what I would like to know is if the condition $\sum_{k=1}^\infty|\beta_k|^2<\infty $ is a necessary condition for all infinite linear combination in a Hilbert Space, or if it is used only for the sake of the proof.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's definitely a necessary condition.
If $x=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \beta_k x_k\in H$ then, since $<\cdot,\cdot>: H\times H\to\mathbb C$, we have that
$$\mathbb C \ni <x,x>=\left<\sum_{k=1}^\infty \beta_k x_k,\sum_{k=1}^\infty \beta_k x_k\right>=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\sum_{j=1}^\infty\bar\beta_k\beta_j<x_k,x_j>=\sum_{k=1}^\infty|\beta_k|^2$$ 
thus an infinite linear combination of $x_j$ can only be an element of $H$ if the series of its coefficients is square summable.

Comment: I see, I absolutely ignored that. Thank you